# How do I fix git after renaming an Xcode project?

Tags: swift, xcode, git

I renamed my Xcode project "time" to "Time" and now when committing I often get an error
`fatal: will not add file alias 'Time/AppDelegate.swift' ('time/AppDelegate.swift' already exists in index)`

I've searched Stackoverflow and I know there are multiple answers to this, but most regards just the renaming of one file - my schema and other keys inside xml's etc has been renamed. I did try  both `git config --global core.ignorecase true` and `git config --global core.ignorecase false` and I did manage to commit something again, but now I think Git goes into a loop when committing files.

On GitHub I have two main folders; Time and time, and when changing a file I think it appends to one and deletes from the other, making each commit registering a change for the other.

I've alse tried to "Fetch file status" as well as doing a pull from GH.

Any suggestions on how to fix this mess?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> On GitHub I have two main folders; Time and time

This is a huge problem. The macOS file system is case preserving but case insensitive. On you local machine, those two names refer to the *same* folder.

I've never had this problem with git but I did have it a few times with Subversion. Probably the simplest thing to do is

- create a disk image that is *case sensitive* (use Disk Utility)[image: Creating a case sensitive image]
- clone your repository into that disk image, that will give you both folders.
- in that new repo, move the files about so they are all in `Time` and delete the `time` folder.
- commit the changes and push to GitHub
- pull the changes into your normal repo in your Xcode location, or delete and reclone.

Comment: Seems like a good idea, but I have a lot of uncommitted changes now. Those aren't in git yet. Is there a simple way to reset git for a project?

Comment: You can use [git stash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning) to temporarily save your changes while you work on the repo. @perage